# Row and Column Reference from Google Query using array functions

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, array-formulas

Is it possible for an array function such as *SCAN, MAP or REDUCE* to be aware of the column or row reference for Query Arrays?

**Example:**

Consider this data - which exists in cell reference A1:B2

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| John | Smith |
| Paul | Jones |

If we apply the below formula to the range:

```
=map(A1:B2, lambda(x, row(x) & "-" & col(x))
```

We would get the below result

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1-1 | 1-2 |
| 2-1 | 2-2 |

However, if we do the following...

Instead of referencing the Range directly, we reference it via a query, eg.

```
=map(query(A1:B2), lambda(x, row(x) & "-" & col(x))
```

We get an error:

> "Argument must be a range."

I understand why this is happening, but I would like to know how can we get the row and column reference back in these cases?

### Updated Information

Assume we had the following array (as a result from a google query):

| SKU ID | Date | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2-Feb-2023 | John |
| 2 | 3-Feb-2023 | Harry |
| 3 | 4-Feb-2023 | Paul |

Using the MAP function, how could we transform the data so that:

- Vlookup of SKU ID to another table, and replace SKU ID with looked up value
- Apply EOMONTH function to Date
- No transformations on Name column

using MAP, if we knew the row number and column number for each entry on the table, then you would be able to apply the correct transformation to each entry and ignore the header and column 3 (name)

Comment: Because `query(A1:B2)` returning values not cell reference. What is your actual goal. You may try `MAKEARRAY()` function.

Comment: can you provide a realistic example of how your query looks like? There may be a workaround.

Comment: Actually, what I am trying to do is use the MAP function and modify / transform certain fields, so generally you would want to ignore row 1 as its the header and then you may want to perform certain operations on column 1, ignore column 2, and some other transformations on column 3 for example

Comment: @z - I have updated the question with additional information

Comment: @Harun24hr - I have updated the question with additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,query({A1:C4}), Λ,chooserows(Σ,sequence(rows(Σ)-1,1,2)),
 vstack(chooserows(Σ,1),
        map(choosecols(Λ,1),choosecols(Λ,2),choosecols(Λ,3),lambda(sku,date,name,{vlookup(sku,A:A,1,),eomonth(date,),name}))))
```

[image]

Comment: beautiful solution, so elegant, I have much to learn, 10 out of 10 for this one

Answer (score 0):

`MAKEARRAY()` would give you same result. Try-

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(query(A1:B2)),COLUMNS(query(A1:B2)),LAMBDA(r,c,r&"-"&c))
```

[image]